# How to redirect with request context to another url in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm new to `Django`. Given a simple user login scenario. I have two templates: `index.html` and `register.html`.

In `register.html`, it's just a simple user register web page and post the user data to a url:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="/register/" method="post">
    ......
</form>
```

And in `index.html`, it shows the user information:

```
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <p>Welcome, {{ user.username }}. Thanks for logging in.</p>
    {% else %}
        <p>Welcome, new user. Please log in.</p>
    {% endif %}
```

Here is the `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'register/form/', views.register_form,name='register_form'),
    url(r'register/', views.register, name='register'),
)+static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Here is the `views.py`:

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')


def register_form(request):
    return render(request, 'register.html')


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        user = User.objects.create_user(username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'])
        user.save()

        user = authenticate(username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'])
        auth.login(request, user)

        return render_to_response('index.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Here is my question:

First, go to this url `register/form/` to fill in the form and submit the data, and then it'll go to url `register/` to process the data and then go to `index.html`. But the url in the browser is still `register/`.

After register, I want the url is `my_domain_name/` rather than `my_domain_name/register/` because if it's still in `my_domain_name/register/`, if I refresh, it'll show whether to submit data again.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You may try https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect . Modify view.py as:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def register(request):
    ...
    return redirect('/')
```